# Odd user agent appearing in IIS logs

Tags: email, redirect, iis, user-agent

Recently, we have had an increase in traffic to one of our servers with the user agent:

Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0)

This server receives click responses from emails, records them and then redirects to another server.

In theory, this user agent is IE 8 running on Windows 7 (32-bit), but the sudden uptick seems odd, especially given that Windows 7 shipped with IE 9.

As these are emails, I have looked through the Outlook user agents, but haven't found a match.  Nor have I found any other mention of this user agent so far.

This traffic is coming from numerous IPs (mostly universities) and appears to be legitimate traffic from customers.

Is anyone aware of an email client, email server, firewall, etc. that may be sending this user agent?

Answer (score 0):

If you never heard of IE 8 compatibility mode, now you should learn it,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537503(v=vs.85)

That's exactly why you see MSIE 8.0. Many software (if they use IE control) might work under that mode, so you have very little control over that.